# Why is Aleksandr Orlov associating with supervillains?

Tags: advertisements

The TV character has numerous off-tv pieces of media, such as an autobiography, as listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare_the_Meerkat), but no where does it explain the recent supervillain animals he is associating with.

Here is the advert:

Comment: Orlov's backstory is not consistently presented. In many adverts he features in fantastical scenes as hero, accidental protagonist or villain; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare_the_Meerkat. This seems to be nothing more than a continuation of that theme

Answer (score 0):

Because the company that uses Orlov to market their website has [changed advertising company](https://www.lbbonline.com/news/a-furry-league-of-supervillains-share-their-schemes-in-comparethemarketcom-campaign).

> The new campaign marks a significant shift for the brand and will see
> much-loved Meerkat Aleksandr Orlov, joined for the first time, by a
> mischievous group of animals to uncover more ways for consumers to
> manage their money than ever before.
>
> The new spot brings to life the ‘good versus bad’ when it comes to
> money management and continues to spotlight that ‘Good Things Happen
> When You Meerkat Your Money’.

and

> The bold through-the-line marketing campaign also includes digital
> out-of-home, paid social, CXM, PR and influencer marketing. Executions
> will see Aleksandr and his mischievous gang appearing in ‘Wanted’
> outdoor treatments, disrupting ad breaks and digital media and
> creating radio takeovers.
>
> Kristin Sonfield, head of brand and communications at
> comparethemarket.com, said: “We are excited for our customers to see
> the new campaign. This is a step change for our brand, as we evolve to
> become the front door to people’s household finances and offer them
> ways to Meerkat their money. We’re hoping loyal followers of the
> Meerkats will love the next chapter of the story as much as we do.”
>
> <sub><sup>[A Furry League of Supervillains Share Their Schemes in Comparethemarket.com Campaign](https://www.lbbonline.com/news/a-furry-league-of-supervillains-share-their-schemes-in-comparethemarketcom-campaign)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's about the advertising company not the character. I'd much prefer an 'in universe' answer, and as such this isn't much use to me unfortunately.

Comment: There's no in-universe. He's just a character in an advert. He's also been in a Star Wars themed montage, traveled on the Titanic and rescued pirate gold. There's no consistency to his backstory whatsoever.

Comment: there's a clear difference between when we see him 'not working' vs. working to advertise insurance/movie ticket tie-ins

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - he's always working.

Comment: Yes, but when he appeared in Star Wars that was him 'acting' as part of his job. He's not 'acting' when he's interacting with the villains.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Says it right there - "*We’re hoping loyal followers of the Meerkats will love the next chapter of the story as much as we do*". This is merely the next chapter of his life,